# mysqli insert data is blank and adding double

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to learn mysqli so I convert my site over. And I was having a hard time on the update part so I decided to take baby steps and go a little at a time.

Well I am trying to switch over the add-item page which uses the INSERT. The issue is, there is nothing being put into the database and it putting 2 blank rows in. (Like 2 items are being added)

I have been wearing this board out with questions and I search for the answers and do trial & error before asking, but I just cannot seem to grasp this mysqli. It works great with mysql, but with it being depreciated, I wanted to switch it over.

post2.php

```
     <?php

        $db = new mysqli("localhost","admin","pass","database"); 

        if(!$db) {
    die('sorry we are having some problbems');
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO new_equip(`id`,`itemname`, `manufacture`, `model`,`serial`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("issss", $_POST['id'], $_POST['itemname'], $_POST['manufacture'], $_POST['model'], $_POST['serial']);

    if(!$stmt->execute()) {
    // Do your error stuff

  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($db));
 }

}
echo $sql;
var_dump($_POST);
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

add-item.php

```
<form method="post" action="post2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3">Item Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="itemname" value="" class="form-control" />
</div> <!-- /.form-group -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3">Manufacture</label>
    <input type="text" name="manufacture" value="" class="form-control" />
</div> <!-- /.form-group -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3">Model</label>
    <input type="text" name="model" value="" class="form-control" />
</div> <!-- /.form-group -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3">Serial</label>
    <input type="text" name="serial" value="" class="form-control" />
</div> <!-- /.form-group -->
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-3">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    &nbsp;
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
</div> <!-- /.col -->
```

Comment: To be honest, you should be using binds anyway http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php but... does `echo $sql;` give you any clues?

Comment: Looks like nothing is being passed _INSERT INTO new_equip(`id`,`itemname`, `manufacture`, `model`,`serial`) VALUES('','','','','')_

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` and `name="Submit"` I can't see how that's presently working. Name attributes are case-sensitive.

Comment: Fred is right. Also you are missing the { } from your `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` block, which means only the first line after it is executed with the condition. Everything else is going to be executed every page load, regardless of form submission (which would explain blank rows). If you turn on error reporting you will likely see a lot of "undefined index" notices where it's trying to use $_POST values that don't exist.

Comment: Using `mysqli_real_escape_string` _in combination_ with prepared statements is of course nonsense. You should try and understand the basic principle before you migrate to PS …

Comment: You have completely changed your question's code. Going from using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to prepared statements. Again, `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` and `name="Submit"` won't fire up anything. It must read as `name="submit"` with a lowercase "s". Plus, where is your form element for `$_POST['id']`? There's nothing in your form to support it. That's why you're getting `Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement`

Comment: I updated my question at the request of AlexL but then pretty much got called stupid because I cannot grasp why it is coming up with array(0) { }. So I guess I will just keep it using mysql until I can figure this out. Thanks for your time Fred, you have been a huge help on this and the other.

Comment: If the row for "id" is an AI, remove it. That's another reason for the error.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you run the query 2 times.

One time here:

```
$result = $db->query($sql);
```

Second time here:

```
if (!mysqli_query($db,$sql))
```

You should replace `if (!mysqli_query($db,$sql))` with `if (!$result)` or just remove `$result = $db->query($sql);`

Prepared statement version:

```
<?php

    $db = new mysqli("localhost","admin","pass","database"); 

    if(!$db) {
    die('sorry we are having some problbems');
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO new_equip(`id`,`itemname`, `manufacture`, `model`,`serial`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("issss", $_POST['id'], $_POST['itemname'], $_POST['manufacture'], $_POST['model'], $_POST['serial']);

    if(!$stmt->execute()) {
        // Do your error stuff

        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($db));
    }

}

echo $sql;
var_dump($_POST);
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: See the edited answer for prepared statement to escape the data. If the inserted data is still blank, make sure you have valid data in `$_POST` variable.

Comment: Got this with prepared statement - Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I've corrected the answer. Should be ok now.

Comment: Warning: mysqli::query(): Empty query in- url line23
Error: Column 'itemname' cannot be null

Comment: Have you checked `$_POST` to make sure that it has proper data in it? What is the output of `var_dump($_POST);` ?

Comment: I believe it does. Here is what the var_dump showed. EDIT- Just got this Error: Column 'itemname' cannot be null

Comment: Well that tells you that there is no post data. In your HTML code, the `target` of the form is `post2.php` but the code listing is for `post.php`. Maybe you're posting the form to the wrong php script. Also you're missing the `{}` for `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) ` conditional block. I've edited my answer with the correct conditional `if` block.

Comment: Thats been fixed, now I am getting Error: Column 'itemname' cannot be null

Comment: Please update your question with the final PHP and HTML code. And make sure that the form's `action` points to the correct PHP script. Your question lists the code for `post.php` but your form sends the data to `post2.php`.

Comment: Remove your code from `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` block and put mine. See my last answer edit.

Comment: I've put the entire PHP script as it appears you don't get it.

Comment: Yes I do, I was editing my post. But thank You.. now I am getting array(0) { }

Comment: And what does that tell you? It tells you that the `$_POST` variable is empty. So it will not get past the condition. That's it for me. If you can't fix it from here by yourself please read a book and do some learning before asking questions about very basic stuff.

Comment: Right, I understand that. I just dont get why it isnt being passed. and it isnt very basic if I am trying to learn. Like I said in my initial question. I have searched and did trial and error. before I posted my question. As you seen from my original question there are many ways to do this and so far everyone has a different answer.